# Why do seismic P waves convert to S waves at an interface?

Tags: refraction, earth

Why does a P wave refract and become an S wave when it hits an interface? What is the mechanism behind this? If P waves are longitudinal and S waves are transverse, how can this change occur?

[image]

Comment: Quick note to those unfamiliar with seismic and/or  optical waves:  "P" and "S" for seismic are different wave *types*, whereas optical/electromagnetic "P" and "S" indicate direction of polarization.

Comment: This picture is from info on  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoeppritz_equations  , so I think the actual question being asked here is "Please explain Zoeppritz step-by-step"